# Matlab pdist2 : Out of memory

Tags: matlab

I have a vector X which contain x and y value in column 1 and 2 respectively.
I make a calcul between each point :

```
Distance = pdist2(X,X);
```

But sometimes I have a problem of memory.

However, I use this matrix in a loop like this :

```
for i:1:n
    find(Distance(i,:) <= epsilon);
    .....
end
```

So, do you know how to make the calcul inside the loop of just the line i of the matrix Distance ?

Thanks

Comment: For one of the inputs to `pdist2` only pass in a portion of `X` (e.g. `pdist2(X,X(1,:))`)?

Comment: maybe pdist2(X(i,:),X) ??

Comment: It's the same thing. I didn't use `i` because I can't see your entire code and don't know what is computed when....

Comment: Could you try to epxlain what you need? You first say you have memory issues (`pdist()` isn't efficient) on the other it sounds you need only portion of the data. Please explain the whole picture and we'll assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I looked for :

```
pdist2(X(i,:),X)
```